# Extract story plots from Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata

### Goal

I want to extract story plots from the English Wikipedia. I'm only looking for a few (~100) and the source of the plots doesn't matter, e.g. novels, video games, etc.

I briefly tried a few things that didn't work, and need some clarification on what I'm missing and where to direct my efforts. It would be nice if I could avoid manual parsing and could get just issue a single query.

### Things I tried

#### 1. [markriedl/WikiPlots](https://github.com/markriedl/WikiPlots)

This repo downloads the `pages-articles` dump, expands it using [wikiextractor](https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor), then scans each article and saves the contents of each section whose title contains "plot". This is a heavy-handed method of achieving what I want, but I gave it a try and failed. I had to run wikiextractor inside Docker because there are known issues with Windows, and then wikiextractor failed because there is [a problem with the --html flag](https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor/issues/247).

I could probably get this working but it would take a lot of effort and there seemed like better ways.

### 2. Wikidata

I used the [Wikidata SPARQL service](https://query.wikidata.org/) and was able to get some queries working, but it seems like Wikidata only deals with metadata and relationships. Specifically, I was able to get novel titles but unable to get novel summaries.

### 3. DBpedia

In theory, DBpedia should be exactly what I want because it's "Wikipedia but structured", but they don't have nice tutorials and examples like Wikidata so I couldn't figure out how to use their [SPARQL endpoint](https://dbpedia.org/sparql). Google wasn't much help either and seemed to imply that it's common to setup your own graph DB to query, which is beyond my scope.

### 4. [Quarry](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Research:Quarry)

This is a new query service that lets you query several Wikimedia databases. Sounds promising but I was again unable to grab content.

### 5. PetScan & title download

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62744338) says I can query [PetScan](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/) to get Wikipedia titles, download HTML from Wikipedia.org, then parse that HTML. This sounds like it would work, but PetScan looks intimidating and this involves HTML parsing that I want to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to do this as Wikipedia content isn't structured as you would like it to be. I'd use petscan to get a list of articles based on the category, feed them in to e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=The%20Hobbit&format=json&prop=sections iterate through the sections and if the 'line' attribute == 'Plot' then call e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=The%20Hobbit&format=json&prop=text&section=2 where 'section' = 'number' of the section titled plot. That gives you html and I can't figure out how to just get the plain text, but you might be able to make sense of https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse

Comment: This worked for me with some modifications: (1) when looking at the section data, I actually needed to grab `index` and not `section`, (2) there is no way to request plain text, but I was able to use `pywikibot` and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66106848) to strip the HTML. Some working code here as a reference:
https://gist.github.com/charlesjlee/c1155752e865273028c0e43e0bbcbd27